# How to connect graphql and prisma in docker containers?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, graphql, prisma

I am trying to build a docker-compose file that run a node.js graphql api that uses prisma and mongodb.
But I got an error **request to http://localhost:4466/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4466** when ever I try to send requests from graphql playground and the same error when I run prisma deploy or just try to ping http:localhost:4466 from inside the graphql container.

I have tried to use the default network and creating new network but I got the same error.
I have tried to use links (which is deprecated) in version 3 but also I got the same error.

P.S I can open the playground of prisma normally in the browser with the link: http://localhost:4466

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    networks: 
      net:
    ports:
    - "80:4000"
    command: wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh http://localhost:4466 -t 30 -- ./run.sh
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    networks: 
      net:
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mongo
            uri: mongodb://prisma:prisma@mongo
    command: /bin/sh.sh
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6
    restart: always
    networks: 
      net:
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: prisma
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo:/var/lib/mongo
volumes:
  mongo:
networks: 
      net:
```

And this is the dockerfile of the web service:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app/

RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile 

RUN yarn global add prisma
```

And this is the run.sh file:

```
echo "prisma deploy command "
prisma deploy
echo "get-schema command"
yarn run get-schema
echo "starting command"
yarn run start
```

Are there anything that I misunderstand, Or what I need to fix to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `http://prisma:4466` as the connection URL in your web container. As your containers will be connected to the same network the name of the container will be DNS name and therefor will be resolved to IP of concrete container.

Answer (score 1):

The `localhost` in your Node application points to the container running Node itself, not your host machine. Replace `http://localhost:4466` with `http://prisma:4466` or `http://<host-machine-local-ip>:4466`

To get host IP on a Unix machine run:

```
hostname -i
```

Or

```
ifconfig | awk '/broadcast/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the content of your `prisma.yml` from

```
endpoint: http://localhost:4466
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
```

to

```
endpoint: http://192.168.99.100:4466
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run your docker container by typing **$docker-compose up -d** -d flag is for running container in detach mode.

Instead of using  endpoint as **http://localhost:4466**  use **http://127.0.1.1:4466** Or check your localhost by the cmd: $localhost -i.
In prisma-binding your constructor should have endpoint as **http://127.0.1.1:4466**.

```
const prisma = new Prisma({
    typeDefs: './src/generated/prisma.graphql',
    endpoint: 'http://127.0.1.1:4466'
});
```